# My copy of Windows 7 is no longer considered valid. What are my options?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I can't seem to locate a phone number for Microsoft that doesn't involve paying $25. This is a legal copy of Windows I previously used on another machine, that I now want to apply (only) to this machine.

Are there perhaps reliable activation cracks available? Microsoft seems to be forcing my hand.

Comment: Activation cracks are illegal buddy. If it is legal, just activate over the phone, which is free.  If you used it on a previous machine as in an OEM, then it isn't legal to move it to another machine anyways.

Comment: -1 for illegality.

Comment: I have a legal license. Not entirely sure that activation cracks are “illegal” so much as against terms of service in that situation. Nevertheless thanks to gethuman.com I was able to solve my problem via the phone without the $25 charge. That number would have been a great answer…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you activate over the phone you can explain this is a re-installation on existing hardware.

However, if you have the OEM version this most likely will not work and involve paying or buying a new Window license. The Retail version can be installed on multiple computers, up to a certain limit...

Comment: OEM's can be reinstalled, but will require you to speak to a person in the 'Activation Department' and supplying them with more information than just the installation number (usually typed into the phone system first)

Comment: It was a license provided through MSDNAA (their partnership with universities).

Comment: Do you know the phone number in question?